# efficient database file trees

Tags: python, database, performance, chat

So I was making a simple chat app with python. I want to store user specific data in a database, but I'm unfamiliar with efficiency. I want to store usernames, public rsa keys, missed messages, missed group messages, urls to profile pics etc.

There's a couple of things in there that would have to be grabbed pretty often, like missed messages and profile pics and a couple of hashes. So here's the question: *what database style would be fastest while staying memory efficient?* I want it to be able to handle around 10k users (like that's ever gonna happen).

heres some I thought of:

- everything in one file (might be bad on memory, and takes time to load in, important, as I would need to load it in after every change.)
- seperate files per user (Slower, but memory efficient)
- seperate files
  per data value

  - directory for each user, seperate files for each value.

thanks,and try to keep it objective so this isnt' instantly closed!

Comment: It's not answers question is instantly closed for, but the question itself. An this one is broad enough to be good candidate for this to occur.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only answer possible at this point is 'try it and see'.

I would start with MySQL (mostly because it's the 'lowest common denominator', freely available everywhere); it should do everything you need up to several thousand users, and if you get that far you should have a far better idea of what you need and where the bottlenecks are.